# websockets - get message from a websocket server and send it to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to learn how websockets work. I am able to get trading data from a websocket server and print it on the console. However, I am trying to understand how I can pass that message into my websocket server so that I can send it to my websocket clients. Basically, I want to print each message on browser.

```
"use strict";

const WebSocket = require("ws");

const binanceWS = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/stratbtc@trade");

binanceWS.on("open", function open() {
    console.log("open action");
});

binanceWS.on("message", function incoming(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now this `binanceWS` will print data when it recieves one. The thing I am trying to do is how I can pass to the `send` eventlistener of my WebSocket.Server object. As you can see an example from https://github.com/websockets/ws wss itself takes a websocket object when there is a connection.

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

Thanks!

**NOTE**: The structure I am talking about is like this. Basically, I will have websocket consumers to get trade data. And within same host (localhost for now) there will be a websocket server. This websocket server will send data to each client websockets.

[image]

**SUCCESS**:
Ok I made it by defining consumer websocket (`binanceWS`) `message` listener in websocket server connection. I am not sure if this is a good way though

```
"use strict";

const WebSocket = require("ws");

const binanceWS = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/stratbtc@trade");

binanceWS.on("open", function open() {
    console.log("open action");
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  binanceWS.on("message", function incoming(data) {
      ws.send(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved this my keeping a global list for websocket clients. And when consumer websocket message event is triggered, it sends every client by traversing list.

```
"use strict";

const WebSocket = require("ws");

const binanceWS = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/eosbtc@trade");

var websocketList = [];

binanceWS.on("open", function open() {
    console.log("open action");
});

binanceWS.on("message", function incoming(data) {
    console.log(data);

    // send data to every websocket client
    websocketList.forEach(ws => {
        ws.send(data);
    });
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {

    // add ws handle to websocket list.
    websocketList.push(ws);

    ws.on("close", function close() {
        console.log("Disconnected");
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please post your client side? I would want to understand how the items in websocketList is retrieved on the client side?

Comment: A little late but... you shouldn't have the need to keep the clients list, according to the documentation (https://github.com/websockets/ws#server-broadcast) you should have the list of connected clients inside wss, which you can use to loop.

Answer (score 1):

**single websocket**

```
//websocket connection event will return a socket you can later use
binanceWS.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("message", function incoming(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // if you want to send that message back to the client who sent it, 
    // you can use send method on the socket
     socket.send(data)
    });
});
```

**Nesting websocket**

```
//websocket connection event will return a socket you can later use
binanceWS.on("connection", function(socket) {
    // create another websocket here
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

    // connect the second websocket
     wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
      // start listening to first websocket incoming messages 
      // if second communication has successully been instantiated 
      socket.on("message", function incoming(data) {
      // send the data using the second websocket
      ws.send(data)
      })
    });
});
```

Then you need to have this minimum code in your client and you will see the interaction between the server and your client

**client**

```
const socket = new WebSocket('server_url'); // Connection opened 
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) { socket.send('send message'); });
```

*Note*: Since you will use the incoming data of a websocket into another, it is best to open the second websocket only if the first one has successfully been opened

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Here you are expecting a client websocket connecting to `binanceWS`. After a connection is established  the client websocket can send message to binanceWS and binanceWS will send that message back?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am kinda confused. I am trying to send data when `binanceWS.on('message')` is triggered. And for this I need to create a new WebSocket.Server and use that websocket server object to send messages

Comment: Actually my piece of code will send data back to the client when `message` event is triggered. It means that on your client, you should have something like this:
`const socket = new WebSocket('server_url');

socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    socket.send('send message');
});` I will update my answer

Comment: Hey edkeveked I updated my post with a small structure that I am trying to accomplish. Based on my structure `binanceWS` a consumer websocket that gets data from an exchange. Then I need to create a websocket server which will send the data I am getting from binanceWS to the client websockets. Was it clear? Thanks!

Comment: I made it and updated my post with the working one. Do you think it is a good way? Or are there any other better ways? Thanks again!

Comment: Your solution follows the general pattern. To spare ressources, I will rather consider open the second websocket only if the first has been successfully connected. I updated the answer